# Is there any difference in 'Present Continuous' and 'Present Participle' And 'Past Perfect' and 'Past Participle'?

Tags: grammar

How do i know whether it is a 'Present Continuous' or 'Present Participle'
For example 
1.He is reading a book.
2.When I came, she had left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Participles** are forms of verbs. In English there are two, the so-called **Present participle**, which always ends in *-ing*; and the **Past participle**, which has various forms: most often *-ed*, but also *-en*, *-t*, and sometimes no ending. 
They have various uses, but can often be used in an adjectival sense, either on their own (eg "the *coming* year") introducing a clause (eg "A building *infested* with rats"

**Present continuous** and **Present (or past) Perfect** are *constructions* which use these participles following a verb: most often *be* or *have*. These are one of the ways in which the participles are used.

So, if a present participle follows a form of the verb *be*, it is probably a continuous tense. (There are occasional exceptions. For example *He is demanding.* is probably an adjectival use: if it were a continuous tense, you would expect an object, eg *He is demanding to be heard.*)

If a past participle follows a form of the verb *have*, then it is always (I think) a perfect tense. (eg *She has gone away.*)

Also note that a past participle can follow a form of *be*, and is usually passive in meaning: *Their victory will be celebrated*.